# Java: Find latest report and output to screen

Tags: java, text, io, report, java-7

I have a program that generates reports. It places every report in the same directory. Each report is a different file, with a naming syntax: `report*number*.txt`Java: print contents of text file to screen. The latest report will have the largest number. How do I have my program find the latest report and output it to the screen when the application is executed?

Comment: What did you try? What is your approach? What is the code you have so far? What is the specific part of what you want to do that you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the latest modified file, try this:

```
public static File lastFileModified(String dir) {
    File fl = new File(dir);
    File[] files = fl.listFiles(new FileFilter() {          
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isFile();
        }
    });
    long lastMod = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    File choise = null;
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.lastModified() > lastMod) {
            choise = file;
            lastMod = file.lastModified();
        }
    }
    return choise;
}
```

Comment: Never thought of that.

Comment: so , think about that , may be help you :)